# enums declaration in class C++, problem getting to enum in class

Tags: c++, class, enums, declaration

I have problem with the declaration of enum in my class.
I had tried to declare it on private, public, outside, in the main, nothing works.
I need to call function in the class from outside and use the enums in the function
here is my code.

```
class Algoritem {
    public:
    enum Optimization { W , A , D };
    enum FenceType { OF , CC };
    enum Eventopa { BR , OR };
    algorithem* OptimalPatrol(double N, int K, double VS, double T, Optimization F,FenceType FT, Eventopa E, double Imax,double P);
};
```

When I need to call OptimalPatrol() I need to input the 3 enums. I can't redeclare them in the main, so how can I input my enums with variable from the main?

Comment: helping out a non-native speaker: the correct spelling is _algorithm_

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to specifiy which class the enums are defined in. So, e.g. call the function like this:

```
OptimalPatrol(N, K, VS, T, Algoritem::W, Algoritem::OF, Algoritem::BR, Imax, P);
```

That way, your compiler knows in which class to look for the enum declarations.

Comment: (An commonly useful alternative is to declare the `enum`s just before the `class`, in the same `namespace`, but which is better depends on whether the simplified concise usage reintroduces the risk of clashes with other symbols in that namespace, and the documentary value of the class-name prefix).